# Listening for all incoming packets to a certain network interface using Boost/ASIO

Tags: boost-asio

I was looking all over the internet to find a way to capture incoming packets from a certain network interface, then I came across PCAP, TCPDUMP, I believe the most commonly used networking library out there is Boost/Asio, so I wanted to use this library in order to capture traffic, but apparently there is no example for using Raw sockets or other classes to listen for incoming packets to a certain NI, I would appreciate any help or examples on this.

Comment: There is a general socket type ([This example shows how to use raw sockets with ICMP to ping a remote host.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#:~:text=This%20example%20shows%20how%20to%20use%20raw%20sockets%20with%20ICMP%20to%20ping%20a%20remote%20host)) but putting adapters in promiscuous mode and sniffing is probably not subject of portable networking. It's the reason that libpcap exists.

Comment: @sehe Libtins was the best option.

Comment: Please consider posting that as answer. Even though library suggestions are off-topic for SO people might have a similar question in the future and find your post. Comments are not durable and certainly not searchable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually found out the best option for sniffing incoming packets was [Libtins](http://libtins.github.io/).

> libtins is a high-level, multiplatform C++ network packet sniffing and crafting library.
>
> Its main purpose is to provide the C++ developer an easy, efficient,
> platform and endianness-independent way to create tools which need to
> send, receive and manipulate network packets.
>
> It uses a BSD-2 license and it's hosted at github.